# Maximize the equation $S=(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...)mod M$ given M, and K list containing certain numbers; x_i is from ith list

Tags: python

To solve this question, I have tried the following code:

```
from itertools import product

k,m=list(map(int,input().split()))
num=[list(map(lambda x: int(x)**2,input().split())) for _ in range(k)]
num=[set(i) for i in num]
combination=list(product(*num))
s=[sum(i)%m for i in combination]
print(max(s))
```

It is working for most of the test cases.

```
Input
3 1000
2 5 4
3 7 8 9
5 5 7 8 9 10

Expected output
206
Actual output
206
Explanation
(5^2+9^2+10^2)%1000=206
```

But it gives different answers for few.

```
Input
3 998
6 67828645 425092764 242723908 669696211 501122842 438815206
4 625649397 295060482 262686951 815352670
3 100876777 196900030 523615865

Expected output
974
Actual output
984
```

Also,
The following code gives the expected answer of 974 for the second input

```
from itertools import product

K,M = map(int,input().split())
N = (list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(K))
results = map(lambda x: sum(i**2 for i in x)%M, product(*N))
print(max(results))
```

What is the difference between the first and second approaches? Why is the first approach not working in some cases?
Is it because of the way I squared the input number initially and formed a combination using product itertools ?

Comment: Are you allowed to ignore some lists?

Comment: One number from each list. Ignoring is not allowed.

Comment: Do you need to convert it to a set? I don't think that affects it, but you never know with these things...

Comment: To me, the code seems unnecessary complex. It could probably be more readable using numpy

Comment: This can be reformulated as a knapsack problem. There is way more efficient ways to solve this problem

Comment: @Larry Not a compulsion, did it to avoid repetition.

Comment: @Jimmy if efficiency were not the issue, is the first approach wrong?